# Undo/redo button in App Inventor 2?

Tags: app-inventor

Is there any undo/redo button in [App Inventor 2](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/)? Surprisingly I haven't found any. Did I miss something?

App Inventor 1 used to have such buttons for the block editor:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** this feature is available again in more recent versions, please see answers below.

Surprisingly UNDO / REDO buttons have been removed in App Inventor 2.

If I can remember correctly they were causing some issues when blocks were undone after removing. [**Here**](https://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=1245&can=1&q=undo&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Status%20Summary%20Owner%20Reporter%20Stars) is the issue which you can star, if you want more advanced tools you should take a look at Java as App Inventor is only the very basics of coding.

Answer (score 1):

It's available in the new blockly version in latest update. (there was some issues with undo in MIT app inventor 2 previously).

Check this link and explore the new features:

http://ai2-test.appinventor.mit.edu

Comment: that's available on the test server, as I told you [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-open-source-dev/BL56WiGMvDo/6QIyq91HEAAJ)... for using this in projects you should wait, until it's available in production...

Comment: taifun, do i remove the answer until it's available in the production.

Answer (score 0):

They are no UNDO/REDO buttons in App Inventor 2, unfortunately.